# After gulp task browser can't find fonts

Tags: css, fonts, gulp, task

After i run my task to copy the fonts from the bower_component, the browser seems to be confused with the correct path.

This is the gulp task for fonts:

```
// Fonts
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src(bowerDir + '/open-sans-fontface/fonts/**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}', function (err) {})
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'fonts'));
});
```

And this is the gulp task for styles:

```
// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return plugins.sass(src + 'styles/main.scss', {
          style: 'expanded',
          loadPath: [
            // './resources/sass',
            bowerDir + '/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets',
            bowerDir + '/font-awesome/scss',
            bowerDir + '/open-sans-fontface'
          ]
        })
      .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'styles'))
      .pipe(plugins.rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
      .pipe(plugins.cssnano())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'styles'))
      .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
      // .pipe(plugins.notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});
```

How do i adjust the gulp file, so the created css-file looks for the right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace). Example:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/styles/main.scss')
    .pipe(plugins.sass())
    .pipe(plugins.replace('original-path/fonts/', 'new-path/fonts/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

If e.g. bootstrap had it's fonts under `original-path/fonts/` that path would now be replaced with `new-path/fonts/` after the `styles` task is run.

Comment: Thanks MadScone but unfortunately nothing changed. I've added the code to my style task: .pipe(plugins.replace(dest + 'style/fonts', dest + 'fonts/open-sans')) but the browser is again still looking in the wrong path

Comment: Your first argument to `replace()` doesn't look right. I don't think the original path to your fonts will be `dest + 'style/fonts'`. I don't know what `dest` is, but assuming it's something like "build"... That would mean `replace()` is replacing `build/style/fonts` with `build/fonts/open-sans`. But open-sans will not be pointing to `build/style/fonts`. I think you probably want something like `plugins.replace('./fonts', './fonts/open-sans')`. The first argument is the original URL that you want to change.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I've now fixed the problem. I took a look at the main.css and played a little with the replace plugin till i got it to work!